# Enabling and disabling multiple buttons in view issue

Tags: ios, ios7

I have a view with 12 buttons. I want to be able to perform the action's button just once when i tap it and then set that specific button disabled. When i tap on another button i want the same thing to happen + set the other buttons enabled. Is there a solution?

Comment: each button has a different action or not?

Comment: Has a different action. Precisely, i apply filters over an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give to each button a tag, and when you tap on a button using method `viewWithTag` you can enable and disable each button:

When you create `UIButton`, you can add:

```
UIButton *button0 = ...
button0.tag = 0;

UIButton *button1 = ...
button1.tag = 1;

//and so on
```

In every action of the buttons, you must pass the id object like this:

```
-(void)tapButtonOne:(id)sender {

   //with this sender you can retrive the tag of the button clicked
   UIButton *button = sender;
   int buttonTag = button.tag

   //now you can check every button and enable the other that haven't the same buttonTag
   //with the first tag = 0 plus 12 the last tag will be 11 so i<12
   for (int i = 0; i<12; i++) {
     //self.view if you have added the buttons on self.view, otherwise you must write your view
     UIButton *buttonTemp = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
     if(buttonTemp.tag != buttonTag) {

       buttonTemp.enabled = YES;
     }
     else {
       buttonTemp.enabled = NO;
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an outlet, create an `IBOutletCollection`.
When you drag from the interface builder to your app, you can change the "Outlet" selection to "Outlet Collection".
Once you've done that for the first button, control drag all your buttons and link them to the same collection.
Connect all buttons to the same IBAction and make sure it specifies the sender (this is the default).
Then, in your action:

```
for (UIButton* button in self.yourOutletCollection){
    if (button == sender){
        // this is the button that was tapped
    } else {
        // all the other buttons go here
    }
 }
```

Enjoy!